# Is there a way I can avoid using a constructor while calling these methods?

Tags: java, string, methods, return

I have this code trying to modify the choice string by adding "wow" to the end of it. I am trying to use a custom class rather than just concatenating Strings because I want to be able to run other methods on it in the future as well.

```java
for(String choice : commands) {
    count++;
    if(goAvailable.contains(choice)) {
        actionApnd("You went to " + new ModifyString(choice).append("wow") + ".");
        //System.err.print(choice + " ");
        break;
    } else if (count == commands.length) {
        actionApnd("Where did you want to go?");
    }

}
```

the ModifyString class (trimmed down):

```java
public ModifyString(String str) {

    stringToReturn = str;
}

public String append(String toAppend) {

    stringToReturn += toAppend;

    return stringToReturn.trim();
}
```

I had this method in the `ModifyString` class and was using it instead of a constructor, but an error message told me I can't run `append` on the type String.

```java
public static String string(String str) {

    stringToReturn = str;
    return stringToReturn.trim();
}
```

Comment: What's `stringToReturn`? Is that a field inside `ModifyString`? If so, you can't access it inside a static method.

Comment: Also, you appear to be reinventing `StringBuilder`, worse. String concatenation is not a good way to accumulate strings.

Comment: Try using Public Variable, and can you share the error message?

Comment: @AndyTurner It's a variable inside ModifyString, however, I would make it static if I was trying to access it from a static context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String string(String str) {

    stringToReturn = str;
    return stringToReturn.trim();
}
```

The issue is that `stringToReturn` is an instance field on `ModifyString`, meaning that it's associated with a specific instance of that class. There is no such instance in a `static` method.

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, given that the return type is `String`: you could simply remove the first statement:

```
public static String string(String str) {
    return str.trim();
}
```

but then you may as well just invoke `str.trim()` directly.

Alternatively, you may have meant to return an instance of `ModifyString`:

```
public static ModifyString string(String str) {
    return new ModifyString(str.trim());
}
```

Note that string concatenation is a bad way to accumulate strings, because it requires copying the existing string in order to do the concatenation.

A better approach would be to use a `StringBuilder`, either directly, or wrapping it:

```
class ModifyString {
  private final StringBuilder sb;

  ModifyString(String str) {
    sb = new StringBuilder(str.trim());
  }

  ModifyString append(String str) {
    sb.append(str.trim());
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I wanted to prepend? I'm not familiar with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Heroshrine [refer to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Specifically, the `insert` method can prepend, with `0` as the first parameter.